# Why oracle trigger on delete is executed when foreign key is set to null

Tags: oracle, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints

I have primary table AAAA and table BBBB which has FK to table AAAA. FK constraint is ON
  DELETE SET NULL.
There is also trigger ON DELETE ON table BBBB.
In this trigger there is delete from AAAA where ...
Why this trigger is executed when delete from AAAA is performed? (Well there is recursion exception, so it is not executed).

```
CREATE TABLE AAAA
  (
    "AAAA_PK"    NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "AAAA_VALUE" NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "AAAA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("AAAA_PK")
  )

CREATE TABLE "BBBB"
 (
  "BBBB_PK" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "BBBB_FK" NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "BBBB_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BBBB_PK"),
  CONSTRAINT "BBBB_AAAA_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("BBBB_FK") REFERENCES AAAA ("AAAA_PK") ON
  DELETE    SET NULL ENABLE
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_ON_AFTER_BBBB_DELETE_ALL AFTER
  DELETE ON bbbb 
 BEGIN 
 -- delete from aaaa where ....
 dbms_output.put_line('TRIGGER EXECUTED');
END;
```

Add some data like AAAA(1,1) and BBBB(1,1)

If I delete line from AAAA I expected that FK in BBBB is set to null, but it fails with

```
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at TRIG_ON_AFTER_BBBB_DELETE_ALL, line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger TRIG_ON_AFTER_BBBB_DELETE_ALL
```

If I have trigger just with output print, it is executed - but I am not deleting from table BBBB!

So why trigger is executed?

Comment: What is that `delete from aaa...` in your trigger? If that is "active" in your real trigger, it **will** cause the recursion.

Comment: Sure, I understand that recursion, but if I leave in trigger just print some line, it is called and works. Question is why is that trigger executed (called) when there is no no delete on table bbbb (and this action should cause trigger execution).

Comment: Reproduced on Oracle 11.1.0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, when deleting the parent, both AFTER DELETE *and* AFTER UPDATE triggers fire on the child table, which is anti-intuitive. I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour or not - possibly a bug but I'm not sure.

However, row-level triggers on the child table only fire as expected - i.e. an AFTER DELETE FOR EACH ROW trigger is *not* fired, but an AFTER UPDATE FOR EACH ROW trigger *is* fired.

Anyway, the way around this is to use AFTER DELETE FOR EACH ROW triggers instead of a statement-level trigger. If needed, record the row IDs in a package to be processed in the after statement trigger.

Comment: Thanks, that workaround with remembering changed lines would be fine, but since we are using more databases we decided to use solution in application backend. Anyway if anybody knows why it behaves like this, please let us know.